# SIGABRT trying to load data using a URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, urlsession

I starting to develop in Swift for iOS (Xcode 9). I need to make a very simple app to check if an URL is available. To begin, I'm trying this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func checkEndpoints(_ sender: UIButton) {
        checkEndpoint()
    }

    func checkEndpoint(){
        let session = URLSession()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            print(response)
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Then, when I press the button I didn't get anything in the screen as result and I get this error: *Thread 1: signal SIGARBT*

Any idea how can I improve this code? Any concern to understand and learn Swift is welcome. Thanks!

PD: image attached with the error after click on button over simulated app.
[image]

More info of the output:

```
2018-06-25 21:45:26.859103-0300 Check enpoints test[67554:3991300] -[NSURLSession dataTaskForRequest:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000015140
2018-06-25 21:45:26.865855-0300 Check enpoints test[67554:3991300] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLSession dataTaskForRequest:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000015140'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f1b31e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b5ba031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f234784 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f135898 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f135278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Check enpoints test                 0x000000010acb052b _T019Check_enpoints_test14ViewControllerC014checkEndpoint_C0yyF + 427
    6   Check enpoints test                 0x000000010acb031b _T019Check_enpoints_test14ViewControllerC14checkEndpointsySo8UIButtonCF + 43
    7   Check enpoints test                 0x000000010acb036c _T019Check_enpoints_test14ViewControllerC14checkEndpointsySo8UIButtonCFTo + 60
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010be573e8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010bfd27a4 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010bfd2ac1 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010bfd1a09 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 580
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010becc0bf -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010becd7c1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4086
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010be71310 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c7b26af __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2796
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c7b52c4 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5949
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f155bb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f13a4af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f139a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f13930b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111679a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010be56057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  Check enpoints test                 0x000000010acb1c07 main + 55
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110394955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Try using `URLSession.shared` instead of a new `URLSession()`

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Comment out checkEndPoint inside your IBAction function to see if the error is caused by storyboard stuff linking. Also change the function name so it differs to other function in the class (which causes infinite loop error) if called incorrectly.

Comment: Alexander: with URLSession.shared I didn't get nothing after click on button.
rmaddy: after click on button in simulation app Xcode show me the image I've attached now.

Comment: That picture does not show where the crash is happening.

Comment: TheNitram: I tried both, commenting the func name (then the button don't do nothing when I've clicked) and changing the name for another one (same message and I didn't see in the screen the output I want of the URL connection).

Comment: rmaddy: more info added in main message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either used the URLSession.shared or instantiate the URLSession with the default configuration:

```
func checkEndpoint(){
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        print(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Hi Christian! I tried exactly this and after click on button I didn't see anything in the screen BUT in the debug output I've got a "Status Code: 200". Great advance, thanks! How can I show same debug output at least in the app screen? Thanks.

Comment: 200 means it the request was successful. what do you mean by you are not seeing anything on the screen? print will just print in the console not in the screen/UI.

Comment: Right, I know that 200 is ok so, in this way the code now is working. I will investigate a little more how can I show it in the screen because it is next step I'l need. Thanks!